# Error in replicating an R function

Tags: r

I wrote a local function which seems running well at some replicates but with an error message at some other number of replicates. I'm frustrated to figure it out so I'd post here to get some helps.

```
#function
impmatch<-function(data, margprob, commonprob, rep, seed=NULL){

  if (!is.null(seed)){set.seed(seed)}

  data<-as.matrix(data)
  n<-nrow(data)
  m<-ncol(data)
  cdata<-data[complete.cases(data), ]

  impi<-function(){
    sdata<-rmvbin(n, margprob=margprob, commonprob=commonprob)
    datai<-matrix(NA, ncol=m, nrow=n)
    for (i in 1:n){
            nna<-sum(is.na(data[i, ]))
            if(nna==0){
              datai[i, ]<-data[i, ]
            } else if(nna==m){
              datai[i, ]<-cdata[sample(nrow(cdata), 1), ]
            } else{
              a<-data[i, ]
              a[is.na(a)]<-"."
              srow<-grepl(paste(a, collapse="-"), apply(sdata, 1, paste, collapse="-"))
              mdata<-sdata[srow,]
              datai[i, ]<-mdata[sample(nrow(mdata), 1), ]
            }
    }
  outi<-apply(datai, 1, sum)
  outi<-ifelse(outi>=1, 1, 0)
  return(outi)
  }
  out<-replicate(rep, impi())
  return(out)
}

#package & foo data
require(bindata)
margprob<-c(0.1, 0.4, 0.3)
cp<-c(0.015, 0.005, 0.003, 0.005, 0.3, 0.07, 0.003, 0.07, 0.1)
commonprob<-matrix(cp, 3,3) 
data<-data.frame(y1=rbinom(100,1,0.2),
                 y2=rbinom(100,1,0.4),
                 y3=rbinom(100,1,0.3))
data$y1[sample(1:100, 10)]<-NA
data$y2[sample(1:100, 20)]<-NA
data$y3[sample(1:100, 15)]<-NA

#test function
#without error
test<-impmatch(data, margprob, commonprob, rep=2, seed=123) 
#with error
test<-impmatch(data, margprob, commonprob, rep=10, seed=123)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument
```

I bet the error comes from the `sample` function, but I have no idea what have caused it and how to fix it.

Comment: Most likely `length(x)` is zero.  You'll have to find out why `nrow(cdata)` is zero.   It's bad practice to refer to variables inside a function which are not explicitly passed to the function. Further,  since you only call `impi` once, why make it a function at all? Just put the code inside your `replicate` call.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it look like the code itself is ok, but R cannot find a solution each time! When I ran it with `test<-impmatch(data, margprob, commonprob, rep=5, seed=123)` sometimes it gave the same error, other times it works just fine. The same goes for `test<-impmatch(data, margprob, commonprob, rep=10, seed=123)`.

As a workaround you can use the `try` function in your code. Which will repeat the process until a working solution is found. I added it in your function below. Hope this helps!

```
impmatch<-function(data, margprob, commonprob, rep, seed=NULL){

  if (!is.null(seed)){set.seed(seed)}

  data<-as.matrix(data)
  n<-nrow(data)
  m<-ncol(data)
  cdata<-data[complete.cases(data), ]

  impi<-function(){
    sdata<-rmvbin(n, margprob=margprob, commonprob=commonprob)
    datai<-matrix(NA, ncol=m, nrow=n)
    for (i in 1:n){
      nna<-sum(is.na(data[i, ]))
      if(nna==0){
        datai[i, ]<-data[i, ]
      } else if(nna==m){
        datai[i, ]<-cdata[sample(nrow(cdata), 1), ]
      } else{
        a<-data[i, ]
        a[is.na(a)]<-"."
        srow<-grepl(paste(a, collapse="-"), apply(sdata, 1, paste, collapse="-"))
        mdata<-sdata[srow,]
        datai[i, ]<-mdata[sample(nrow(mdata), 1), ]
      }
    }
    outi<-apply(datai, 1, sum)
    outi<-ifelse(outi>=1, 1, 0)
    return(outi)
  }
# editted code starts here.
  cll <- 0
  while(cll==0){

    out<-try(replicate(rep, impi()),silent=T)

    if(class(out)=="matrix"){

      cll=1

    }

  }

  return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. The error occurs when `sum(srow)==1`, which leads to `nrow(mdata)==NULL`. I modified the function as this and it works fine now.

```
impmatch<-function(data, margprob, commonprob, rep, seed=NULL){

  if (!is.null(seed)){set.seed(seed)}

  data<-as.matrix(data)
  n<-nrow(data)
  m<-ncol(data)
  cdata<-data[complete.cases(data), ]

  impi<-function(){
    sdata<-rmvbin(n, margprob=margprob, commonprob=commonprob)
    datai<-matrix(NA, ncol=m, nrow=n)
    for (i in 1:n){
            nna<-sum(is.na(data[i, ]))
            if(nna==0){
              datai[i, ]<-data[i, ]
            } else if(nna==m){
              datai[i, ]<-cdata[sample(nrow(cdata), 1), ]
            } else{
              a<-data[i, ]
              a[is.na(a)]<-"."
              srow<-grepl(paste(a, collapse="-"), apply(sdata, 1, paste, collapse="-"))
              #edited
              if(sum(srow)<=1){
                datai[i, ]<-cdata[sample(nrow(cdata), 1), ]
              } else{
                mdata<-sdata[srow,]
                datai[i, ]<-mdata[sample(nrow(mdata), 1), ]
              }
            }
    }
  outi<-apply(datai, 1, sum)
  outi<-ifelse(outi>=1, 1, 0)
  return(outi)
  }
  out<-replicate(rep, impi())
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: Good detective work. Did you use `debug` or just run test cases?

Comment: No, I didn't. I just tested under `srow==0` and `srow==1` where most likely the error is from.